# how do I invoke jython from the python shell (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, jython

I like the python shell in ubuntu, it looks pretty, and I want to run jython from there. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just start a jython shell by typing jython?

Or are you trying to run ipython with jython? or do you want to run a jython program/script from an interactive python shell?

P.S.
Possibly

```
import subrocess                                 
f=subprocess.Popen(['jython', '/usr/share/jython/Lib/test/test_xmllib.py'],stdout=subprocess)
for f.stdout.readline:
    ...
```

Comment: jython in the unix shell works, but yeah, I'm trying to run jython from the  (for lack of a better term) interactive shell

Comment: the jython interactive shell? or a jython process?

Comment: import subrocess                                   f=subprocess.Popen(['jython', '/usr/share/jython/Lib/test/test_xmllib.py'],stdout=subprocess)